# How to tell a queue_name is available

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

I could know whether a queue_name is available or not in queue.yaml from `UnknownQueueError` when passed unknown queue_name.

```
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue
taskqueue.add(url="/mytask", queue_name="foo", method="GET")
```

However, I prefer to know it without exception handling. Are there any API?

Comment: At the moment you could duplicate the app.yaml (use a symlink) and then you can read/parse it for the queue definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently an API. You can vote for the issue
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8405